# spl_autoload_register does not display anything on the screen

Tags: php

I would like to get the class name through spl_autoload_register, but it doesn't work and it doesn't return anything

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
  echo $className;
});

class CreateRating
{
  public function test()
  {
    return 'Test';
  }

}

$test = new CreateRating();
$test->test();
```

I need to know the names of the Classes.
Through autoload I thought spl_autoload_register might be a valid option.
However, it doesn't return anything to me even through var_dump

Comment: `spl_autoload_register` is only called if the class cannot be found. Because it is right there, there's no need to invoke a lookup function to find it. Remove the class definition, and your autoloader is invoked: https://3v4l.org/ovN8p

Comment: That's because the autoloader is not triggered.